# Newlines in HTTP

Tags: http, standards-compliance

The HTTP 1.1 standard says that newlines are CRLF. However `wget`, `lynx`, and `firefox`, all accepts a response in UNIX format.

Is it acceptable for a HTTP parser to simply skip all carriage returns in the header?

Comment: Many well-known http clients accept responses which are not standard compliant in many ways. `Is it acceptable for a HTTP parser to simply skip all carriage returns in the header?` Acceptable to whom?

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.3: "*The line terminator for message-header fields is the sequence CRLF. However, we recommend that applications, when parsing such headers, recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore the leading CR.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RFC 9112, section 2.2:](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9112#section-2.2)

> Although the line terminator for the start-line and fields is the
> sequence CRLF, a recipient MAY recognize a single LF as a line
> terminator and ignore any preceding CR.

If you were to build a recipient (client or server), it would be RFC compliant to parse requests that only send an LF as line terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is acceptable. From [§3.5. *Message Parsing Robustness* of RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.5):

> Although the line terminator for the start-line and header fields is
> the sequence CRLF, a recipient MAY recognize a single LF as a line
> terminator and ignore any preceding CR.